# javascript bind this undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i'm trying to bind "this" to a google firebase function but i'm not able to get this value inside the promise. Please check my code below.

```
this.props.getUser.linkWithCredential(y)
                .then((response) => {
                    ***this.props.history.replace('/');***
                }).catch((error) => {
                switch (error.code) {
                    case 'auth/provider-already-linked':
                        this.setState({formError: 'already been linked to the user'});
                        break;
                    case 'auth/invalid-credential':
                        this.setState({formError: '(otp-03) Please contact customer service for more details.'});
                        break;
                    case 'auth/credential-already-in-use':
                        this.setState({formError: 'Mobile number is already linked with another account. Please contact customer service for more details.'});
                        break;
                    case 'auth/invalid-verification-code':
                        this.setState({formError: 'OTP code is wrong, Please enter the correct code.'});
                        break;
                    case 'auth/invalid-verification-id':
                        this.setState({formError: '(otp-04) Please contact customer service for more details.'});
                        break;
                    default:
                        this.setState({formError: '(otp-05) Please contact customer service for more details.'});
                }
            })
```

so when call (this.props.history.replace('/');) i'm getting undefind for  "this" whey im not able to access it? and how can i use bind here?

Comment: If you really where getting an error for **`this`** being `undefined`, then you would not be able to access `this.props.getUser` in the first place (i.e. `this.props.history.replace('/')` would never be executed). Please provide a [mcve] and the actual error. We can only help you if you provide accurate and complete information.

Comment: yes this is my problem i need to know how can i access "this" how can i use bind in this situation?
if i put "console.log(this)" before "this.props.getUser.linkWithCredential(y)" i got "this" value however if i put it inside the promise ".then((response) => {
                    ***this.props.history.replace('/');***" i will get undefined !!

Comment: `.bind` would have to be called on the function that contains the code you posted. That's why I have asked you to provide a [mcve]. What you posted does not suffice to determine the issue.

Comment: Regarding your comment edit: That's not possible. `this` inside the .`then` callback refers to the same value as it does outside (because you are using an arrow function): https://jsfiddle.net/87r0fo8t/ . Or are you not actually using an arrow function? Again, this would be much simpler to investigate if you provided a [mcve].